# Check if String contains number whilst ignoring punctuation - Java

Tags: java

I need to read a String and then change all the numbers (from 0 - 12, inclusive) to the word for that number i.e. one, two,...twelve.

For example:
This costs 1 dollar, but this is 12.

would be modified to:
This costs one dollar, but this is twelve.

I tried this code

```
        String[] line = s.split(" ");
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String word : line){
            try {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(word);
                if (map.containsKey(i)){
                    stringBuilder.append(map.get(i));
                } else
                    stringBuilder.append(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                stringBuilder.append(word);
            } finally {
                stringBuilder.append(" ");
            }
        }
        stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length()-1);
```

(the map just contains numbers 0-12 and their word equivalents)

The output was: This costs one dollar, but this is 12.

Obviously, the full-stop is the problem here; is there anyway I can ignore the punctuation?

Comment: Are you familiar with regex? That would be an easier way to find numbers in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: consider the logic in your parseInt with Regex:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(word.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", ""));
```

This will evaluate if the word is an integer by removing the punctuation before hands (but keeping the string as is).

Comment: I thought about that, but then how do I replace the punctuation afterwards?

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer, Please, check if it is the desired solution.

Comment: Thank you @Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
    s = s.replaceFirst(matcher.group(1), map.get(matcher.group(1)));
}
```

I look for numbers and keep replacing them while there are numbers left.

Comment: The problem I has with looking for numbers using that regex was that it was picking up numbers in words, which I didn't want in this particular scenario

Comment: Can you give an example of numbers in words? Perhaps this regex will work for you: \\b(\\d+)\\b

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this.

```
            String s = "2, 12, 2, 2, 12, 2";
            Map<String, String> map = Map.of("2", "two", "12", "twelve");
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d+)\\b").matcher(s);
            while (m.find()) {
                s = s.replaceFirst(m.group(1), map.get(m.group(1)));
            }
            System.out.println(s);
```

- `()` is a capture group
- `\\b` is a word boundary designator

To make this a tad more efficient, `m.find()` takes an `int` to decide from where to start the search.  Using `m.start()` as the start of the previous matched token you can compute the next best place to start the pattern match.